# Rails has_one with polymorphic Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem when I try to access relationships or attributes of my models. I have the following code:

```
class Occupation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :occupationable, polymorphic: true
end
```

A user can have multiple occupations and these occupations have specific relationships and attributes.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :occupations, dependent: :destroy
end

class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :occupation, as: :occupationable
end

class Psychologist < ApplicationRecord
 has_one :occupation, as: :occupationable
end

class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :occupation, as: :occupationable
  has_many :children
end
```

The problem occurs in the Parent classes. A parent can have multiple children, but how can I access these children?

I tried the following but unsuccessfully:

```
ID | OCCUPATIONABLE_ID | OCCUPATIONABLE_TYPE | USER_ID | CREATED_AT              | UPDATED_AT              
---|-------------------|---------------------|---------|-------------------------|-------------------------
1  | 1                 | Parent              | 1       | 2018-07-26 13:49:06     | 2018-07-26 13:49:06           


User.find(1).occupations.where(occupationable_type: "Parent").children
```

> NoMethodError (undefined method `children' for
>   Occupation::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x0000559d4c601898

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.find(1).occupations.where(occupationable_type: "Parent").children
```

As indicated by the error, returns an `ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation` which does not have the method `children`.

If you do:

```
User.find(1).occupations.find_by(occupationable_type: "Parent")
```

That will return a single `occupation` record. But, you don't want the `occupation`, you want the `Parent`. So, try:

```
User.
  find(1).
  occupations.
  find_by(occupationable_type: "Parent").
  occupationable.
  children
```

But, if that `user` doesn't have an `occupation` with `occupation_type` "Parent", then you're going to get some errors (because you'll try to call `occupationable` on a `nil` object).

So, you could try:

```
User.
  find(1).
  occupations.
  find_by(occupationable_type: "Parent")&.
  occupationable&.
  children
```

I don't know where you're using that code. But wherever it is, you need to know a lot about how your models are set up. You might consider going for some encapsulation. Something, perhaps, like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :occupations, dependent: :destroy

  def occupation(type)
    occupations.
    find_by(occupationable_type: type)&.
    occupationable
  end

  def children
    occupation('Parent')&.children
  end

end
```

In which case you could do something like:

```
User.find(1).children
```

And now you don't need to know anything about how your models are set up in order to find the children.

Down the road, I imagine you might end up doing something like:

```
class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :occupation, as: :occupationable
  has_many :students
end
```

In which case, you might do:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :occupations, dependent: :destroy

  def occupation(type)
    occupations.
    find_by(occupationable_type: type)&.
    occupationable
  end

  def children
    occupation('Parent')&.children
  end

  def students
    occupation('Teacher')&.students
  end

end
```

You're going to end up with redundancy (maybe a lot). And, it might get tricky when you go to find all the `Teachers` for a `Student` or `Parents` for a `Child`. But, that's a whole other kettle of fish.